# Tic Tac Toe game winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tic-tac-toe

I understand that this works and all but is there a better way of doing this ?

```
    Button clicked = (Button)sender;
        if (turn)
        {
            clicked.Text = player;
        }
        else {
            clicked.Text = cpu;
        }

        turn = !turn;
```

Comment: Those buttons are never added to your form so I have no idea which button you are clicking, but its not the ones in your array. What happened to your `InitializeComponent()` method?

Answer (score 6):

When you click a button it's click event handler is executed. This calls your `tictactoe` function. In there your code is executed from top to bottom, which checks the `.Text` of the first button in your array first and adjusts it. Then Your If..Else block ends. On the next click this repeats. This leads to the behaviour.

Instead you should cast the `sender` object to `Button` and only work on this. No need for the whole `If..Else` block. `Sender` is the object that raised the event (here: the button that was clicked).

```
public void tictactoe(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Text)) {
        b.Text = player;
    }
}
```

Afterwards you will also need to flip the `player` from `X` to `O` or vice versa but you will find out how to do this I reckon. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. I added this and it works but only when I click the button that the sender that was type casted from clicked changes the text but then again if clicked the program changes the x to o

Comment: I have made changed to further explain what is being said

Comment: @june1992 Best would probably be if you set the `.Enabled` property to False as well in the Click event. Furthermore, Don't change your originial question completely or the answers make no sense anymore. Open another question, or append the new data at the bottom.

Comment: @june1992 You also stripped the `string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Text)` from my answer out of your implementation. That is of course important.

Answer (score 1):

Change the tictactoe to this:

```
public void tictactoe(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    if (button.Text == "")
        button.Text = player;
}
```